# Bool query or filter query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an expression/query : ("text" started_with "hello" OR "text" started_with "hi") OR ("select" is "first_option" AND "correct" is "true" ) . Can you show me the way to use both of bool and filter query correctly in Elastic Search to solve this expression?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the given expression/query using "[prefix query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)" along with [boolean query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and [term query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-term-query.html). Try as follows

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "prefix": {
                    "text": {
                        "value": "hello"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "prefix": {
                    "text": {
                        "value": "hi"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "select": [
                                    "first_option"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "correct": [
                                    "true"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can I use sth like this : `"query" : {match_all: {}}, "filter": {"or":[
            {
                "prefix": { }
            } ....
        ]` ?

Comment: Yes. The same can be done using a filter also either by using bool filters which will be similar to the above or by using BoolAnd and BoolOr filters as you have written

Comment: That's mean "prefix" is working find with "or" and  "and" filter ? I read that "or" and "and" filter should be used for script, geo-bounding, choice.

Comment: You can use the prefix filter with "or" "and" or "Boolean" filters. You have read correctly that it is recommended to use Boolean filter in case of filters other than script/George-bounding because it can make use of the cached filter bit sets. Having said that you can still use "or" and "and" filter also. They are sometimes beneficial as they are executed sequentially and filters out the result as they are passed down the chain.